# Prospective homebuyer and sole director of a dormant company; am I employed or self-employed for mortgage purposes? (UK)

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, mortgage

I am a full time employee for a large company over which I have no control (i.e. no directorship or anything of the sort) and I am paid more than enough for the size of mortgage I have applied for.

I am also, however, the sole director of a private limited company, formed very recently (within the last 2 months) in my own name. I did this for a couple of reasons:

- to protect my name
- to prepare for potential side work in the future

The company is dormant for the purposes of both Companies House and HMRC. It was formed with my employer's blessing, for the purposes of managing any affairs I conduct outside of my main employment. It does not, has never and will not trade, not for the considerable future at least.

My question is: am I employed, or self-employed? Or perhaps both? And which should I specify on my mortgage application?

I have the option of striking off the company, but would prefer not to.

Answer (score 3):

You're employed. You should also mention the company directorship if the application form asks about it.

Comment: Whether this answer is correct or not, I upvoted because this is what I want to be correct :D ty